# Does there exists a continuous function $f: \overline{B(0,1)}(\subset\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$ which is real-valued on $\partial \overline{B(0,1)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does there exists a continuous & non-constant function $f: \overline{B(0,1)}(\subset\mathbb{C})\to\mathbb{C}$  which is real-valued on $\partial \overline{B(0,1)}$ where $f$ is holomorphic inside $B(0,1)$?

Comment: Sure, $f(z) = 1$ works. Did you forget a constraint that $f$ should be non-constant?

Comment: If the function is real valued on $|z| = 1$, then it must constant on the $|z| = 1$. Then we can use identity theorem to say that $f$ must be constant on $|z| \le 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer well, you are right. I want to find a non-constant function $f$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: Do you know about harmonic functions?

Comment: @Tanuj I don't understand why $f$ must be constant on the $|z|=1$. Could you explain it in detail? thank you.

Comment: I learn  a little about it. what do i need to solve this problem?

Comment: What can you say about the harmonic function $u(z) = \operatorname{Im} f(z)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer  Sorry, I cannot think anything...can you give me more hints?

Comment: For the question you asked me, use Cauchy Riemann equations. And what Daniel wants you to think about is the Maximum Principle.

Comment: @Tanuj I think I understand what you mean. I will have a try. thank you.